# Docker swarm configure failover to nextcloud

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-registry

I need to deploy docker swarm failover on 3 servers on one of them db and nextcloud on the others only nextcloud but at the same time they all must interact correctly with db, i tried to use docker-compose this way, but other servers just don't see the db. Please help me solve the problem.

Here is my docker-compose

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  nextcloud:
    image: nextcloud
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
    environment:
      - NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_USER=admin
      - NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin_password
      - NEXTCLOUD_DATA_DIR=/var/www/html/data
      - NEXTCLOUD_TRUSTED_DOMAINS=your-domain.com
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - nextcloud-net
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "wget -q --spider http://localhost || exit 1"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3

  db:
    image: mariadb
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=db_root_password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=nextcloud_password
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - nextcloud-net

networks:
  nextcloud-net:
    driver: overlay

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  db:
```